# PostgreSQL:select value after update

Tags: sql, postgresql, crud

I want use select statement after updating a table in postgresql

for example

```
 update mytable 
 set val1 = 'Foo' 
 where val13=1234 and val12=12
```

now am using

```
select val2 from mytable 
where val14=(select max(val14) from mytable)
```

this to get `val2` after the update statement.So my question is how to do both update and select in a single statement ?

Comment: Your `select` uses a where clause on `val14` which is not changed by your update statement. How does the `select` relate to your `update` statement? In general: to get the updated rows, simply add `returning *` to the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you do like this with the help of [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with cte as (
update mytable set val1 = 'Foo' where val13=1234 and val12=12 returning *
) 
select * from cte where val14=(select max(val14) from mytable )
```